# MYSQL query with PHP pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am trying to write a script that pulls a specific query from a MYSQL database and then paginates the results.

I think I know what the solutions are its just a question of my lack of knowledge on how to implement / script them.

Here is my script that is partially working :

```
<?php
$tstart = 0; 
$tend = 0;
//$tpage = 0; // the start page
//$tpages = 0; // number of pages
$tpagelinks = ""; // stores the output pagination
$ttotal = 0; / total number of results
$trows = 5; // number of results per page
$online = ""; // stores the results to display

$dbhost = "localhost"; 
$dbuser = "****_models"; 
$dbpass = "****";

$dbcon = @mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die('Database error: ' . mysql_error());

$db = mysql_select_db('****_cammodels', $dbcon) or die('Database error: ' . mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM cbmodels WHERE gender='f' AND status='Public' AND age<='22'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "\nQuery: $query");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $online .= "#". $ttotal . " \n";
  $online .= $row['status'] . "/" . $row['name'] . "/" . $row['gender'] . "/" . $row['age'] . "\n";
  $online .= "<br>\n";
  $ttotal ++;
 }
 $tstart = ($tpage * $trows) - $trows;
 $tend = $tstart + $trows;
 if ($tend > $ttotal) { $tend = $ttotal; }
 $tpages = floor($ttotal / $trows);
 if ($ttotal % $trows != 0) { $tpages ++; }
 if ($tpage > $tpages) { $tpage = 1; }

 if ($tpage > 1) { $tpagelinks .= "<a class='allonlinepages_url' href='new_from_db.php?page=" . ($tpage - 1) . "'>PREVIOUS</a>\n"; }

 for ($ti = 1; $ti <= $tpages; $ti ++)
 {
 if ($tpage == $ti) { $tpagelinks .= "$ti \n"; }

    else { $tpagelinks .= "<a class='allonlinepages_url' href='new_from_db.php?page=$ti' >$ti</a>\n"; }
 }

 if ($tpage < $tpages) { $tpagelinks .= "<a class='allonlinepages_url' href='new_from_db.php?page=" . ($tpage + 1) . "' >NEXT</a>\n"; }

echo $online;
echo $tpagelinks;

mysql_close($dbcon);
?>
```

What it is doing is showing all the results found in the database, the pagination count seems to be showing the correct number of pages but the links are wrong / do not show the next page of results.

I think I need to query the database to get a row count for the pagination first and then calculate the number of pages, then do another query to obtain the results maybe store that in another array as results per page ? or something to that effect.
I have tried many times and the script above is the closest I have gotten to get it almost working all my other attempts just break the script and either produce strange results or none at all.

The script I made to pull the data from the actual feed to store in the database itself flagging online and offline works correctly so I have not included that since it is a separate script anyway.

Thank you in advance for any help given Guys.

*EDIT*
Removed all the none working code RE: Comments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, first you need to find out the total number of records. Then run the query again, this time with a LIMIT at the end of your query. For example LIMIT 0, 10. This example returns 10 results starting with record 0 (the first record). If you dynamically set the first record of the limit results using a variable, you can have it update it with every page.  For each page you can calculate what you want the starting record to be. For example, $offset= $recordsperpage * page number.

I'm not sure exactly what your variables are, so I won't toy with your script. Here's an example I had used for a project that I know works.
Example script:

```
//Use mysqli object instead of mysql_xxx, better security
$db3= new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

     //how many records I want per page
    $perPage= 9;

    //I'm passing the startrecording as a Get variable in the page links 
    if($_GET['startingrecord']){
        $startingRecord=trim($_GET['startingrecord']);
    }

    //but if there is no get variable, start at record zero
    else {
        $startingRecord=0;
    }


    //prepare your query
    $stmt3 = $db3->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT file, category, P.productID, price, title, price * (1- sale) FROM Products AS P INNER JOIN OrderProducts AS OP ON P.productID NOT IN (Select productID from OrderProducts) Left JOIN Sale AS S on P.productID= S.ProductID ORDER BY productID DESC");

    // You can bind parameters if necessary, but it's not here

    //execute the query and store the result
    $stmt3 -> execute();
    $stmt3->store_result();

    //determine the number of total rows
    $numberRows= $stmt3->num_rows;

    //close the db
    $db3 -> close;

   //Reopen with limits this time.
    $db3= new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);


    $stmt3 = $db3->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT file, category, P.productID, price, title, price * (1- sale) FROM Products AS P INNER JOIN OrderProducts AS OP ON P.productID NOT IN (Select productID from OrderProducts) Left JOIN Sale AS S on P.productID= S.ProductID ORDER BY productID DESC LIMIT ?, ?");
    // bind the startingrecord from the get variable and the perpage variable.
     stmt3->bind_param("ii", $startingRecord, $perPage);

    //you use ceiling to make sure if that if there's a remainder, you have an extra page for the stray results
    $pages= ceil($numberRows/ $perPage);

   //This is me generating the page links
    for ($i=1; $i<= $pages; $i++) {
        if ($i==1){
            $start=0;
        }
        else{
            $start= ($i-1) * ($perPage);
        }
        echo "<a href='#' onclick='gallery(\"startingrecord=".$start."\")'>".$i." </a>";
    }   

    $stmt3 -> execute();
    $stmt3->store_result();
    $stmt3->bind_result($file, $category2, $productID, $price, $title2, $sale); 

    while($stmt3->fetch()){ 
    // do whatever you want to your result

     })
```

Comment: Ok, I have implemented those changes and now what I am getting is the correct number of results in the list but only 2 pages in the pagination however when you click the 2nd page it does show the next set of results... I echoed the var in count and it only shows 1 result though ?

Comment: I added the amended script to the original post just in case you don't notice it, Thanks... (I could include the url to the test page I suppose but it is hosted on an adult domain so I do not think that would be acceptable here)

Comment: Be careful of off-by-one errors. I've written pagination code several times and there are several places where you need to round up or add one that doesn't immediately make sense.

Comment: None of it is making much sense at the moment lol, I changed the calculations about a bit and made no progress... Other than confirming that it is only pulling 10 rows from the database, so I changed the var age<='22' to '42' and it is still only showing 2 pages 5 results on each ! when I know for a fact there is at least 25 possible matches for that query.

Comment: I will show you a pagination script I wrote a few days ago that you can use as a base. I will post it as soon as I am able. Now that I look at your code with a little more detail I noticed you are using deprecated objects...

Comment: That would be helpful please, though I am starting to think maybe there is a problem in the way I am trying to retrieve the data ? a variation of this works fine when its getting taken from a live XML feed but put it in a database and filter it like I am trying to do and all sorts of problems crop up... Thank you all for the continued help on this, greatly appreciated.

Comment: I editted my post. Please let me know if it helped you. If not you'll have to see if there's something wrong with your query.

Comment: Ok, I plugged my bits into your script and am getting this error : Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result() [mysqli-stmt.bind-result]: Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in /home/pussygen/public_html/my_scripts/CB/cb_test.php on line 72 I know what it is telling me but far as I can see I do have the correct number or parameters... The previous query does work and displays the relevant results but not when I try and paginate it... *edited my post again to show new code* thanks.

Comment: Making zero progress with this exhausted everything I can think of and tried lots of variations on the above without success just very mixed results, can anyone else offer up some advice please ? other than go back to playing computer games lol

Comment: I rewrote it after finding another example that was quite similar to xsearingheaven script, but using a different technique to pull the database info (one that made more sense to me), I am going to flag the answer as being correct because in essence it is... thank you for the help xsearingheaven and pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
ul.pagination {
font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
height: 100%;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 20px 0;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0; }
ul.pagination li.details {
background-color: white;
border-color: #C8D5E0;
border-image: none;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px 1px 2px;
color: #1E598E;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 8px 10px;
text-decoration: none; }
ul.pagination li.dot {
padding: 3px 0; }
ul.pagination li {
float: left;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 3px 0 0; }
ul.pagination li:first-child {
margin-left: 0; }
ul.pagination li a {
color: black;
display: block;
padding: 7px 10px;
text-decoration: none; }
ul.pagination li a img {
border: medium none; }
ul.pagination li a.current {
background-color: white;
border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
color: #333333; }
ul.pagination li a.current:hover {
background-color: white; }
ul.pagination li a:hover {
background-color: #C8D5E0; }
ul.pagination li a {
background-color: #F6F6F6;
border-color: #C8D5E0;
border-image: none;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px 1px 2px;
color: #1E598E;
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 8px 10px;
text-decoration: none; }
</style>
<?php
/******************************************pagination*****function*****************************************/
function pagination($per_page = 10, $page = 1, $url = '', $total){ 
$adjacents = "2";
$page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page); 
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page; 
$prev = $page - 1; 
$next = $page + 1;
$lastpage = ceil($total/$per_page);
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;
$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
{ 
$pagination .= "<ul class='pagination'>";
$pagination .= "<li class='details'>Page $page of $lastpage</li>";
if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
{ 
for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
{
if ($counter == $page)
$pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
else
$pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter'>$counter</a></li>"; 
}
}
elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
{
if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2)) 
{
for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
{
if ($counter == $page)
$pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
else
$pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter'>$counter</a></li>"; 
}
$pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
$pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
$pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>"; 
}
elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
{
$pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}1'>1</a></li>";
$pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}2'>2</a></li>";
$pagination.= "<li class='dot'>...</li>";
for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
{
if ($counter == $page)
$pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
else
$pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter'>$counter</a></li>"; 
}
$pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
$pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lpm1'>$lpm1</a></li>";
$pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lastpage'>$lastpage</a></li>"; 
}
else
{
$pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}1'>1</a></li>";
$pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}2'>2</a></li>";
$pagination.= "<li class='dot'>..</li>";
for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
{
if ($counter == $page)
$pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>$counter</a></li>";
else
$pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$counter'>$counter</a></li>"; 
}
}
}

if ($page < $counter - 1){
$pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$next'>Next</a></li>";
// $pagination.= "<li><a href='{$url}$lastpage'>Last</a></li>";
}else{
//$pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Next</a></li>";
// $pagination.= "<li><a class='current'>Last</a></li>";
}
$pagination.= "</ul>\n"; 
} 
return $pagination;
} 
/****************************************////**pagination*****function*****************************************/
?>



<!---------------------------pagination------------------------------------------------->
<?php 
//error_reporting(0);
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","accounts");
$page=1;//Default page
$limit=2;//Records per page
$start=0;//starts displaying records from 0
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']!=''){
$page=$_GET['page'];
}
$start=($page-1)*$limit;
?>


<!---------------------------pagination-------end------------------------------------------>

<table width="100%" >
<tr>
<td>

<?php

$query = mysqli_query($con,"select * from receipts");
$rows=mysqli_num_rows($query);
//newly registerd on top
$query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from receipts order by r_id ASC LIMIT $start, $limit");


if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,1)){
?>
  <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="1px #f8f8f8" width="100%" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;border:1px solid #e8e8e8">  
  <tr>
  <td id="class1">Name</td>
  <td id="class2"><?php echo $row['party_name'] ;?></td>
  </tr>
    <tr><td id="class1">Roll No</td>
    <td width="700px" id="class2"><?php echo $row['receipt_no']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="class1" width="170px">Date</td>
    <td id="class2"><?php echo $row['date1']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

<?php
}}

?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
if(empty($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = 1;
}
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}
echo '</table><table>';
echo "<tr><td>";

echo pagination($limit,$page,'try.php?id='.$id.'&page=',$rows); //call function to show pagination

echo "</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
</div>
```